# Python Twitter - Tweepy to post unique content using data from txt or JSON files

Tags: python, post, random, bots, tweepy

I have developed a very basic Twitter bot using Python & Tweepy. It is successfully posting a tweet to twitter and I can modify the text in this line of code: `response = client.create_tweet( text='Testing' )` to make different tweets

The full code I am using for this is:

```
import tweepy

client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key="XXXXX",
                    consumer_secret="XXXXX",
                    access_token="XXXXX",
                    access_token_secret="XXXXX")
# Create Tweet

response = client.create_tweet(
    text='Testing'
)
print(f"https://twitter.com/user/status/{response.data['id']}")
```

What I am trying to figure out is how I can code a Bot to randomly read data stored in file(s) and put it altogether to formulate a readable sentence or paragraph a little bit like how a mailmerge works. Here is an example, there are 3 files or 3 values:

```
Value1
Check out this, View this, See this
Value 2
product, item, piece
Value 3
on our online shop, on our store, on our website
```

If the bot was able to read and select data at random it could pick any of the data from the files or values in any order, put them together and it would make sense as a sentence or a paragraph

After researching I see that using text or JSON files might be a possibility. I followed a JSON tutorial and recreated an example that looks like this for text and images:

```
[
  {
    "text": "hi",
    "image": "/image1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "text": "hello",
    "image": "/image2.jpg"
  }
]
```

I think I have worked out how to read the JSON file with this code:

```
import json
with open(r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Python\test.json") as f:
    info = json.load(f)

randomChoice = random.randrange(len(info))
print (info[randomChoice])
```

The thing I am really struggling with is the best way to achieve this and how then to create the code that will post the tweet formulated with the random data it has selected

This is what I have so far as I attempt to combine Tweepy and the abilty to read in data from the JSON file but I can't get it to work as I don't know how to post the data it has read in to Twitter:

```
import tweepy
import random 
import json
with open(r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Python\test.json") as f:
    info = json.load(f)

client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key="XXXXX",
                    consumer_secret="XXXXX",
                    access_token="XXXXX",
                    access_token_secret="XXXXX")
# Create Tweet

randomChoice = random.randrange(len(info))
print (info[randomChoice])

response = client.create_tweet(
    text='NOT SURE HOW TO CODE THIS PART SO TWEEPY POSTS RANDOMLY SELECTED DATA'
print(f"https://twitter.com/user/status/{response.data['id']}")
```

I am brand new to Python and Tweepy so have only a very small understanding but would really appreciate any help on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**About the storage:**

You could read your file(s) and parse each line with the `split(",")` method, but JSON is probably a best solution since it is already formatted.

You want a list of alternatives (which are lists of strings), so why don't you simply use a list of lists ?

You JSON file would be like:

```json
[
    ["Check out this", "View this", "See this"],
    ["product", "item", "piece"],
    ["on our online shop", "on our store", "on our website"]
]
```

**About your Python code:**

You don't need to generate a random index to select an element in a list:

```py
randomChoice = random.randrange(len(info))
print (info[randomChoice])
```

The random module can do it for you:

```py
random.choice(info)
```

**About the sentence building:**

You can now cross the main list, select an alternative from each list of alternatives and add it to the sentence that you will post:

```py
full_sentence = ""

for alternatives in data:
    selected_alternative = random.choice(alternatives)
    full_sentence += ' ' + selected_alternative
```

**The final code:**

```py
import json
import random

# You can start by loading the JSON file

with open(r"test.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# You can then build your full sentence

full_sentence = ""

for alternatives in data:
    selected_alternative = random.choice(alternatives)
    full_sentence += ' ' + selected_alternative 

# You can now post your full sentence on Twitter

client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key="XXXXX", ...)
response = client.create_tweet(text=full_sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for helping me to get this all working. I have been modifying the JSON file and tweaking the code and now have a script that is posting to twitter just as intended

Here is my final code:

```
import tweepy
import random
import json

# Start by loading the JSON file

with open(r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Twitterbot\test.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# Building the full sentence from values in JSON file

full_sentence = ""

for alternatives in data:
    selected_alternative = random.choice(alternatives)
    full_sentence += ' ' + selected_alternative 

# You can now post your full sentence on Twitter

client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key="XXXXX",
                       consumer_secret="XXXXX",
                       access_token="XXXXX",
                       access_token_secret="XXXXX")

response = client.create_tweet(text=full_sentence)
print(f"https://twitter.com/user/status/{response.data['id']}")
```

Cheers

Jamie